# Using Salts in Hashing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table like this:

```
   create table [User] (ID int identity not null,EmailAddress varchar(50), [Password] nvarchar(128),primary key (ID))
```

My reading is telling me that I should add a salt to the table:

```
alter table [user] add salt nvarchar(128)
```

If a user creates an account in the application then I believe the SQL should be as follows:

```
declare @RandomNumber as varchar(32)
set @RandomNumber=rand();
insert into [user] (emailaddress,[password],salt) values ('test@hotmail.co.uk',hashbytes('sha2_256','passwordvalue' + @RandomNumber),@RandomNumber)
```

Then lets say the user wants to authenticate.  The SQL would be like this:

```
select * from [user] where [password] = hashbytes('sha2_256','passwordvalue' + salt)
```

The last SQL statement returns nothing, which proves it is incorrect.

Comment: Just FYI, this approach doesn't add much safety to your password. All these hash algorithms are very fast. If someone has access to your table, when he sees these fields he only has to try a few combinations of hash algorithms and will be able to crack your passwords. For example, he could easily come up with your formula, use it with a password dictionary and if only one matches, you are done. It would take some minutes at most. If you are concerned about security, I recommend do you use bcrypt or any other **slow** hash: http://blog.tcs.de/using-the-bcrypt-hash-algorithm-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Use varchar and not nvarchar, there convertion probleme or declare @RandomNumber as nvarchar(32) like this:

```
 declare @RandomNumber as nvarchar(32)
 set @RandomNumber=rand();
 insert into [user] (emailaddress,[password],salt) values ('test@hotmail.co.uk',hashbytes('sha2_256','passwordvalue' + @RandomNumber),@RandomNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have changed @RandomNumber to an nvarchar and it now works.  I assume it is ok to use nvarchar for the password and salt?

Comment: Have I approached this correctly i.e. combining the password and salt in the password value?

Comment: I honestly do not know. I can only found error in your code (if you can check i have answer to you question ;)  )